# How do I set up IPv6 on my Airport Extreme?

Tags: internet, airport, network

I am trying to set up IPv6 on my Airport Extreme. According to AT&T / BellSouth, my network is IPv6 ready.

### Network Setup

I currently have two parts to my network setup.

1. Westell Model 6200 modem (IPv6 ready)
2. AirPort Extreme (fifth generation)
3. AirPort Express (the last model that plugs directly into the wall)

My modem is plugged directly into the wall via a DSL cable, and then my router is connected to the modem via an Ethernet cord.

### Setting Up IPv6

[image: AirPort Utility Setup]
I tried setting this up on my own in 2012, but the interface of AirPort Utility has changed drastically since then, and I also recall losing all Internet capabilities when I "set it up" last time, so I want to make sure I do it correctly this time.

Upon choose a manual configuration, I'm greeted with different options about whether I want to choose a Native or Tunnel Mode, whether I want to enable IPv6 Connection Sharing, and more.

[image: Example of Options]

I'm not sure which of these options is the "preferred" method, or what is required of me to properly configure AirPort Extreme to use IPv6.

I am willing to plug and play different configuration options to see what works best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the "Configure IPv6" menu, select "Automatic".
2. In the "IPv6 Mode" menu, choose "Native".

That should be all that's needed. The device should be able to autodetect the rest of its settings.

If that doesn't work, then you may need to check the settings with your ISP.

Source / more info: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH5098

Comment: Is there a way I can test my IPv6 configuration?

Comment: The easiest method is to run the automated tests [here](http://test-ipv6.com/). It'll tell you whether IPv6 is working, and it'll also check for some common IPv6 problems. It also has [some very useful instructions](http://test-ipv6.com/broken.html) for troubleshooting broken IPv6.

Comment: Uh-oh, seems AT&T and BellSouth may not be supporting it like they said they were... `Your DNS server (possibly run by your ISP) appears to have no access to the IPv6 Internet, or is not configured to use it. This may in the future restrict your ability to reach IPv6-only sites.` I'll have to contact my ISP later to resolve this.

Comment: If the other tests all passed, then it's probably OK. Many consumer devices don't yet support DNS servers advertised over IPv6, even if they otherwise support IPv6. This isn't necessarily an issue: DNS will simply run over IPv4 instead, and most DNS servers still return AAAA records over IPv4. So apart from the initial name resolution, which will work over IPv4, the rest of the IPv6 traffic will generally work fine. (Note: I'm not sure whether the Airport Extreme supports DNS advertisements over IPv6). If any other tests failed, then sort them out first.

Comment: Do you know what the checkbox that says "enable ipv6 connection sharing" does? Find it after clicking the "internet options" button at the bottom of the "Internet" pane of the Airport utility.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I came across it looking for the same information - especially what the 'Enable IPv6 Connection Sharing' option did. So, I decided to update this thread on that information:

A [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/3yv60s/what_does_enablingdisabling_ipv6_connection/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) from ~2016 asks what the 'Enable IPv6 Connection Sharing' is for. The answer there (from an `Apple Certified`-marked responder) says:

> It allows IPv6 communication alongside IPv4...

I used an online [IPv6 test](http://test-ipv6.com) pointed to by my ISP. With 'Enable IPv6 Connection Sharing' selected, I was able to pass the tests. When that box was unchecked, the test said that I didn't have an IPv6 address at all.

Note: I had the other two options selected as advised by [@bennettp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/130058/20728)'s answer. This gave me an IPv6 address and DNS servers from my ISP.

Comment: for me the internet does not even work properly without selecting Enable IPB6 connection sharing.

Comment: That may be dependent on your provider, @JoãoNunes . Some are enforcing/highly encouraging users to move to IPv6, while others are sorta crawling in that direction...